# Convert XBox 360 Borderlands save to Xbox one GOTY

Tags: xbox-one, borderlands

I think I just threw away thirty bucks.

I have the Borderlands Triple Pack for the 360. Been playing it for years.  Picked up the Xbox One, converted the saves to the cloud, loaded the disc, it set up the One version of the game, and found the save.

But the One version of the game didn't include the DLC.

So I figured, OK, they're both on sale this weekend, I'll pick up the One-native versions of them.

Aaaand the One-native GOTY edition of the game doesn't find my 360 save.

So, I'm annoyed.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you end up finding a solution for this?